# Could not find driver - PHP and SQLServer

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, wamp

I've done every step of the link [PDO MSSQL Server - Driver not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246007/pdo-mssql-server-driver-not-found) and continues to give the following message:

> "could not find driver".

I do not know what to do. I'm using:

```
Wamp
Apache Version: 2.4.9
PHP Version: 5.5.12
Server Software: Apache / 2.4.9 (Win32) PHP / 5.5.12
```

As a suggestion follows the output of the code @VolkerK:

ini file: C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini

```
extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_gmp.dll
extension=php_intl.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_shmop.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_sockets.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
extension=php_xsl.dll
```

Comment: when and where does this erroc occur?

Comment: on that topic last message says: I got the wrong extension loaded from the supplied ones by MS. I needed to use php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts rather than  php_sqlsrv_53_nts ... So do you have the right one ??

Comment: @lino When I try to access the database.